# RVM & Unicorn deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, unicorn

My RVM is installed as root.
When I'm trying to start unicorn socket, it prints

```
user@9001-3:~$ /etc/init.d/unicorn start
Starting myapp app: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
unicorn.
```

But if I type

```
user@9001-3:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
```

`/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/unicorn` path exists.

My unicorn config: https://gist.github.com/1010519

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/etc/init.d/unicorn` doesn't know where to find Ruby because it's managed via RVM. Normally, your `.bashrc` or similar file is executed and sets up the environment; this doesn't happen in init scripts (or likely anything else executed by root).

The solution is to use wrappers. For example, to create a binary called `system_ruby` that loads up RVM's 1.9.2p180 environment and *then* executes `ruby`, execute the following:

```
rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.2-p180 system ruby
```

For more information and more details, check out [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905704/how-does-rvm-work-in-production-with-no-users-logged-in/5925914#5925914), which addresses a similar problem.

Comment: I executed this comand and nothing was changed. `/etc/init.d/unicorn start
Starting DPP.cz.cc app: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory unicorn.`

Comment: If you build an executable called `system_ruby` you'll need to update your `/etc/init.d/unicorn` script to use it instead of `ruby`.

Comment: There are only paths to unicorn.rb and to unicorn binary. How to change my `/etc/init.d/unicorn`? It is here https://gist.github.com/1010519

Comment: Ah, that helps a lot. In that case it's probably Unicorn itself that can't find Ruby. I'd run the wrapper command again, but for Unicorn instead (`rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.2-p180 system unicorn`), this will create an executable called `system_unicorn`. Use the path given by `which system_unicorn` for your `DAEMON` line in the init script. This is similar to what I explain in [this blog post](http://brandontilley.com/2011/01/29/serving-rails-apps-with-rvm-nginx-unicorn-and-upstart.html).

Answer (score 1):

Symlink also works,

```
which ruby<your version>
ln-s /ruby/path/ruby<your version> /ruby/path/ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

Type :
`which ruby` (show the ruby bin path) then type this : `ln -s (change_to_ruby_path) /usr/bin/env/ruby` (construct the correct access for your system)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this for me

```
rvm --default use <version>
```