# postfix pipe mail to ruby script: 'require GEM_NAME' does not load gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I am trying to setup postfix which pipe the received mail to the ruby script. I created one user `deploy` which runs the script file from `postfix/master.cf`. When mail received postfix calls and executes the ruby script but `require 'resque'` does not load the resque gem in that script.
Here is the error log from `/var/log/mail.log`.

```
Jul 12 15:45:42 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01 postfix/pipe[3652]: 94ECE82A15: to=<deploy@mailet.in>, relay=myservice, delay=0.15, delays=0.05/0/0/0.1, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (Command died with status 1: 
"/var/www/mail_getter/email_receiver.rb". Command output: /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
 `require':cannot load such file -- resque (LoadError)  from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' 
 from /var/www/mail_getter/email_receiver.rb:4:in `<main>' email receiver...... )
```

The `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
myservice       unix  -         n       n       -       2       pipe   flags=XhqFBR user=deploy:deploy argv=/var/www/mail_getter/email_receiver.rb
```

Here is the `/var/www/mail_getter/email_receiver.rb`:

```cs
#!/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
puts 'email receiver......'
require 'rubygems'
require 'resque'
require 'redis'

class EmailReceive
  @queue = :incoming_email_queue

  def initialize(content)
    Resque.enqueue(EmailReceive, content)
  end
end
EmailReceive.new($stdin.read)
```

*note: I tried using* `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` too.

Here is the `/etc/postfix/aliases`:

```
myservice:      deploy
```

Here is the `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
myhostname = mail.mailet.in
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydomain = mailet.in
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Here is the `/etc/postfix/header_checks`:

```
/To:.*@mailet.in.*/ FILTER myservice:
```

Here is the `rvm list` output:

```
 =* ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.7.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

*note: I also tried with requiring gems from absolute path.*

Comment: I would change the email script to dump out some information to the console to confirm that it is running as the user `deploy` and not your Postfix user, then confirm that its `$PATH` is set properly, then confirm that its [`gem environment`](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-environment) is set properly.

Comment: I inspect into it and found the user is `deploy` and gem path is `/.gem/ruby/2.5.0 /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0`. Additionally I unpacked the requires gem in the gem path

Comment: RVM isn't really the best way to manage Ruby for production code like this, typically what I've seen is something installed by the system or compiled manually. RVM is geared for interactive users, not headless system users. You can read some more here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5905704/3784008 (but it's fairly old info) My recommendation would be to use a system version of Ruby or compile it yourself if your system doesn't have the right version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a ruby from `wrappers` dir while calling a script from postfix.

Worked config for `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
 myservice unix    -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=XhqFBR user=deploy argv=/home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.5.1/ruby /var/www/mail_getter/email_receiver.rb
```